# Pass data one page to another

Tags: react-native, navigation

I want to pass Email_id, one page to another page but it shows error

I used the navigation, to jump to another page and for sending data

My first file named - Onboarding.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Image, TextInput, View, Alert
} from "react-native";

import Toast, {DURATION} from 'react-native-easy-toast'
import { Block, Checkbox, Text, theme } from "galio-framework";
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Button, Icon, Input } from "../components";
import { Images, argonTheme } from "../constants";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen");

class Register extends React.Component {

constructor(props) { 
    super(props) 
    this.state = {

    UserName: '',
      UserEmail: '',
      UserPassword: ''
    } 
  }

  UserLoginFunction = () =>{

 const { UserName } = this.state;
 const { UserEmail }  = this.state ;
 const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;


fetch('http://demo.weybee.in/react/User_Login.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

  username: UserName,

    email: UserEmail,

    password: UserPassword

  })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        // If server response message same as Data Matched
       if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
        {

            //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.

            this.refs.toast.show('Login successful', 500, () => {
            const { navigation } = this.props;
            navigation.navigate("Profile",{Email: UserEmail});
    });
        }
        else{

          Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

  }
  render() {

    return (
      <Block flex middle>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <ImageBackground
          source={Images.Onboarding}
          style={{ width, height, zIndex: 1 }}
        >
          <Block flex middle>
            <Block style={styles.registerContainer}>
              <Block flex={0.25} middle style={styles.socialConnect}>
                <Image 
                style={{width: 90, height: 90, marginTop:13}}
                source={require('./fitness.png')} />
                <Block row style={{ marginTop: theme.SIZES.BASE }}>   
                </Block>
              </Block>
              <Block flex>
                <Block flex={0.17} middle>
                  <Text color="#656f7a" size={20}>
                   Fight for fitness
                  </Text>
                </Block>
                <Block flex center>
                  <KeyboardAvoidingView
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    behavior="padding"
                    enabled
                  >
                    <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        style={{borderRadius:50, borderWidth:5}}
                        onChangeText={UserName => this.setState({UserName})}
                        borderless
                        placeholder="Name"
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="hat-3"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>
                    <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        style={{borderRadius:50, borderWidth:5}}
                        onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}
                        borderless
                        placeholder="Email"
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="ic_mail_24px"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>
                    <Block width={width * 0.8}>
                      <Input
                        style={{borderRadius:50, borderWidth:5}}
                        onChangeText={UserPassword => this.setState({UserPassword})}
                        password
                        borderless
                        placeholder="Password"
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="padlock-unlocked"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />

                    </Block>

                    <Block middle>
                      <Button color="primary" style={styles.createButton} onPress={this.UserLoginFunction}>
                        <Text bold size={14} color={argonTheme.COLORS.WHITE}>
                          Log In
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                      <Toast ref="toast"
                      style={{backgroundColor:'#131313'}}
                      textStyle={{color:'white',fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                      position='top'/>
                    </Block>
                  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </Block>
              </Block>
            </Block>
          </Block>
        </ImageBackground>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}
```

My second file - Profile.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  Platform
} from "react-native";
import { Block, Text, theme } from "galio-framework";

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Button, Input, Icon } from "../components";
import { Images, argonTheme } from "../constants";
import { HeaderHeight } from "../constants/utils";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const thumbMeasure = (width - 48 - 32) / 3;

class Profile extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Block flex style={styles.profile}>
        <Block flex>
          <ImageBackground
            source={Images.ProfileBackground}
            style={styles.profileContainer}
            imageStyle={styles.profileBackground}
          >
            <ScrollView
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              style={{ width, marginTop: '25%' }}
            >
              <Block flex style={styles.profileCard}>
                <Block middle style={styles.avatarContainer}>
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: Images.ProfilePicture }}
                    style={styles.avatar}
                  />
                </Block>

                <Block flex>

                  <Block middle style={styles.nameInfo}>
                    <Text bold size={28} color="#32325D">
                      { this.props.navigation.state.params.Email }
                    </Text>
                    <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        editable = {false}
                        placeholder="Email"
                        value = { this.props.navigation.state.params.Email }
                        style={{marginTop:20, borderRadius:30, borderWidth:3}}
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="nav-right"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>
                      <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        editable = {false}
                        placeholder="Mobile Number"
                        style={{borderRadius:30, borderWidth:3}}
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="nav-right"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>
                    <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        editable = {false}
                        placeholder="Gender"
                        style={{borderRadius:30, borderWidth:3}}
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="nav-right"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>

                  </Block>

                      <Block middle>
                      <Button color="primary" style={styles.createButton} onPress={this.UserLoginFunction}>
                        <Text bold size={14} color={argonTheme.COLORS.WHITE}>
                          Edit Info
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </Block>
                </Block>
              </Block>
            </ScrollView>
          </ImageBackground>
        </Block>

      </Block>
    );
  }
}
```

I verify the username, email, and password from the server in Onboarding.js file.
I want to send email to Profile.js file

**Error is:**

[image]

**Onboarding Screen**

[image]

**Profile Screen**

[image]

**My Screen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Easing, Animated } from "react-native";
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from "react-navigation";

import { Block } from "galio-framework";

// screens
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Onboarding from "../screens/Onboarding";
import Pro from "../screens/Pro";
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";
import Register from "../screens/Register";
import Elements from "../screens/Elements";
import Articles from "../screens/Articles";
// drawer
import Menu from "./Menu";
import DrawerItem from "../components/DrawerItem";

// header for screens
import Header from "../components/Header";

const transitionConfig = (transitionProps, prevTransitionProps) => ({
  transitionSpec: {
    duration: 400,
    easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(4)),
    timing: Animated.timing
  },
  screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
    const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps;
    const thisSceneIndex = scene.index;
    const width = layout.initWidth;

    const scale = position.interpolate({
      inputRange: [thisSceneIndex - 1, thisSceneIndex, thisSceneIndex + 1],
      outputRange: [4, 1, 1]
    });
    const opacity = position.interpolate({
      inputRange: [thisSceneIndex - 1, thisSceneIndex, thisSceneIndex + 1],
      outputRange: [0, 1, 1]
    });
    const translateX = position.interpolate({
      inputRange: [thisSceneIndex - 1, thisSceneIndex],
      outputRange: [width, 0]
    });

    const scaleWithOpacity = { opacity };
    const screenName = "Search";

    if (
      screenName === transitionProps.scene.route.routeName ||
      (prevTransitionProps &&
        screenName === prevTransitionProps.scene.route.routeName)
    ) {
      return scaleWithOpacity;
    }
    return { transform: [{ translateX }] };
  }
});

const ElementsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Elements: {
    screen: Elements,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: <Header title="Elements" navigation={navigation} />
    })
  }
},{
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#F8F9FE"
  },
  transitionConfig
});

const ArticlesStack = createStackNavigator({
  Articles: {
    screen: Articles,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: <Header title="Articles" navigation={navigation} />
    })
  }
},{
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#F8F9FE"
  },
  transitionConfig
});

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: (
          <Header white transparent title="Profile" iconColor={'#FFF'} navigation={navigation} />
        ),
        headerTransparent: true
      })
    }
  },
  {
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" },
    transitionConfig
  }
);

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: <Header search options title="Home" navigation={navigation} />
      })
    },
    Pro: {
      screen: Pro,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: (
          <Header left={<Block />} white transparent title="" navigation={navigation} />
        ),
        headerTransparent: true
      })
    }
  },
  {
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#F8F9FE"
    },
    transitionConfig
  }
);
// divideru se baga ca si cum ar fi un ecrna dar nu-i nimic duh
const AppStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Onboarding: {
      screen: Onboarding,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: () => {}
      }
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
      navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <DrawerItem focused={focused} title="Home" />
        )
      })
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileStack,
      navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="Profile" title="Profile" />
        )
      })
    },
    Account: {
      screen: Register,
      navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="Register" title="Account" />
        )
      })
    },
    Elements: {
      screen: ElementsStack,
      navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="Elements" title="Elements" />
        )
      })
    },
    Articles: {
      screen: ArticlesStack,
      navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="Articles" title="Articles" />
        )
      })
    }
  },
  Menu
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStack);
export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of navigator screen you are using?

Comment: Well it seems you are not sending anything because email is undefined. Try to console.log `this.props.navigation` in profile.js screen and post output here.

Comment: @EshantBist I added those files, please check and guide me

Comment: @DavidFutera from the answer [as he guides me], I used this.props.navigation.getParam("Email"); my page navigate to profile page but my Text Component is empty [It didn't get anything or it passes empty string? ]

Comment: as @DavidFutera suggested can you try console.log(this.props.navigation) to see list of params inside navigation? maybe nothing is sent.

Comment: @DavidFutera When I tap on remote Js debugging, it says = windows cannot find chrome make sure you typed the name correctly

Comment: @DNA.h  When I tap on remote Js debugging, it says = windows cannot find chrome make sure you typed the name correctly

Comment: @AakashThoriya you don't need remote JS debugging. Simply write `console.log(this.props.navigation)` in your code and you should see output in terminal where you run `npm start` command.

Comment: In your **AppStack**, please could you try to change this : 
**Profile: {screen: ProfileStack,...}**  by this :  
**ProfileStack: {screen: ProfileStack,...}**  ?

Comment: @WilliamBridge thank you from the bottom of my heart. It is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.Email
```

to

```
this.props.navigation.getParam("Email")
```

Comment: My page navigate to another page but Text is empty

Comment: I think you had to change onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})} to onChangeText={text=> this.setState({UserEmail: text})}

Comment: thank you for your support but I still didn't get anything.

Comment: from your support and above suggestions, finally, I succeed